Angular material select json value to show only the specific value with keyvalue
I want to show the value sent as json in the backend, and only the waterType value that comes with the json value with angular material select. Here, when the angular select is run with keyvalue, all json values ​​come. How can I filter these values ​​so that only waterType is selected?

json
{
  "waters": [
    {
      "id": "f657db7a-9f0a-40b3-9af7-e9c7b1e02df7",
      "conductance": 900,
      "conductanceMax": 1300,
      "createdDate": "2024-08-10T01:45:36.1906201",
      "updatedDate": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
      "waterType": "xxxxx"
    },
}

WaterService
export class WaterServiceService {

  constructor(private httpclient: HttpClient) {

  }


  getWaters(): Observable<List_Water_Type[]> {
    return this.httpclient.get<List_Water_Type[]>('https://localhost:7131/api/Water/')
  }

createComponent:
  private loadWaters(){
    this.waterService.getWaters().subscribe(data=>{this.waters=data})
  }

html:
<div class="form-details">
  <div *ngFor="let ot of waters | keyvalue">
    <ng-container >
      <mat-form-field>
        <mat-label>Water</mat-label>
        <mat-select formControlName="water" [(ngModel)]="selectedWater" >
          <mat-option  *ngFor="let water of waters[ot.key] | keyvalue" [value]="water.key" >
            {{water.value | json}}
          </mat-option>
        </mat-select>
      </mat-form-field>
    </ng-container>
  </div>
</div>


You are mixing angular reactive forms (formControlName) and angular template driven forms (ngModel) which is a bad idea, you have to choose between either of the two. Learn more in angular.dev.
Second issue is the HTML is too complicated, you just need to set the array to the select and it will render without any issues.
<div class="form-details">
  <mat-form-field>
    <mat-label>Water</mat-label>
    <mat-select [(ngModel)]="selectedWater">
      <mat-option *ngFor="let water of waters" [value]="water.id">
        <!-- changed here! -->
        {{water?.waterType}}
        <!-- changed here! -->
      </mat-option>
    </mat-select>
  </mat-form-field>
</div>

We also need to create interfaces for the API response as well as the waters array.
Service:
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';
import { List_Water_Type } from 'src/example/select-overview-example';

export interface WatersResponse {
  waters: List_Water_Type[];
}

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class WatersService {
  constructor(private httpclient: HttpClient) {}

  getWaters(): Observable<WatersResponse> {
    return of({
      waters: [
        {
          id: 'f657db7a-9f0a-40b3-9af7-e9c7b1e02df7',
          conductance: 900,
          conductanceMax: 1300,
          createdDate: '2024-08-10T01:45:36.1906201',
          updatedDate: '0001-01-01T00:00:00',
          waterType: 'xxxxx',
        },
      ],
    }) as Observable<WatersResponse>;
  }
}

Component TS:
import { Component, inject } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { MatInputModule } from '@angular/material/input';
import { MatSelectModule } from '@angular/material/select';
import { MatFormFieldModule } from '@angular/material/form-field';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { WatersResponse, WatersService } from 'src/app/waters.service';

export interface List_Water_Type {
  id: string;
  waterType: string;
  conductance: number;
  conductanceMax: number;
  createdDate: Date | string;
  updatedDate: Date | string;
}

/**
 * @title Basic select
 */
@Component({
  selector: 'select-overview-example',
  templateUrl: 'select-overview-example.html',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [
    MatFormFieldModule,
    MatSelectModule,
    MatInputModule,
    FormsModule,
    CommonModule,
  ],
})
export class SelectOverviewExample {
  waterService = inject(WatersService);
  selectedWater = '';
  waters: List_Water_Type[];

  ngOnInit() {
    this.loadWaters();
  }

  private loadWaters() {
    this.waterService.getWaters().subscribe((data: WatersResponse) => {
      this.waters = data.waters;
    });
  }
}

Stackblitz Demo

hello Dear  Murali
When I use it as you specified, I get an error like the one below. I think it gave an error like this because I used keyvalue. Property 'id' does not exist on type 'unknown'.ngtsc(2339)
create.component.ts(31, 9): Error occurs in the template of component CreateComponent.
any    Property 'id' does not exist on type 'unknown'.ngtsc(2339)
create.component.ts(31, 9): Error occurs in the template of component CreateComponent.
any
No quick

@Mustafasan you have to define an interface for the array, but a quick fix is to wrap it with $any, please share a working stackblitz will share the proper solution with an interface

I shared with you the interface I use, but I have no previous experience with stackblitz. Maybe this interface alone will be enough?         export interface List_Water_Type{
    id:string;
    waterType:string;
    conductance:number;
    conductanceMax:number;
    createdDate:Date;
    updatedDate:Date

}


@Mustafasan updated my answer with a simpler approach, try to work with arrays instead of keyvalue  pipe, it just makes the code very complicated without adding any value! also please either use reactive or template driven forms, do not mix the two together

Thank you very much for the information you gave. It only works when I define the data into the array as you did below. But what should I do when pulling the data from the backend? I think I need to use httpclient here?      return of({
waters: [
{
id: 'f657db7a-9f0a-40b3-9af7-e9c7b1e02df7',
conductance: 900,
conductanceMax: 1300,
createdDate: '2024-08-10T01:45:36.1906201',
updatedDate: '0001-01-01T00:00:00',
waterType: 'xxxxx',
},

@Mustafasan This of({}) is just to mock an API call, you can use the normal Http API call to get the data, I was assuming the API is the same structure as the object you shared in the question

My API model is as I shared. But can you make an example of how I can pull data from the backend with httpclient?

@Mustafasan This code will work fine getWaters(): Observable<WatersResponse> {     return this.httpclient.get<WatersResponse>('https://localhost:7131/api/Water/')   } do a console.log and check the structure in the browser console, then compare the code, in my code I am accessing the property waters inside the response

I am getting the data as I described, but the select does not work in the UI part. No data comes.

ResponseBody: {"waters":[{"id":"f657db7a-9f0a-40b3-9af7-e9c7b1e02df7","conductance":900,"conductanceMax":1300,"createdDate":"2024-08-10T01:45:36.1906201","updatedDate":"0001-01-01T00:00:00","waterType":"xxxx"},{"id":"5e993ca3-ba64-48b5-8a2c-177f1a0a498d","conductance":1300,"conductanceMax":1700,"createdDate":"2024-08-10T01:46:43.6556526","updatedDate":"0001-01-01T00:00:00","waterType":"xxxxx"},{"id":"04f2d29a-da32-4da7-b828-d1cabf14caf6","conductance":0,"conductanceMax":0,"createdDate":"2024-08-10T01:47:05.1787236","updatedDate":"0001-01-01T00:00:00","waterType":"xxxxx"}]}

@Mustafasan its difficult to understand what is wrong, but you can use console.log and check each individual line to see where its going wrong. I think the problem is inside the subscribe of the component, mainly this line this.waters = data.waters;

I solved the problem by using pipe and map before subscribing. Thank you very much for your help.

@Mustafasan no problem!
